# Removing spaces from data in a column of dataframe in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is the command I am using to remove "." from data in a df column in spark-scala which is working fine

```
rfm = rfm.select(regexp_replace(col("tagname"),"\\.","_") as "tagname",col("value"),col("sensor_timestamp")).persist()
```

But this is not working to remove leading spaces in the same columnar data

```
rfm = rfm.select(regexp_replace(col("tagname")," ","") as "tagname",col("value"),col("sensor_timestamp")).persist()
```

There is no error . It just fails to remove any leading spaces that i see in the data

Input : rfmshow()

```
+--------------------+-----+----------------+
|           tagname  |value|timestamp       |
+--------------------+-----+----------------+
|  P.A               |101.5|  1.409643313E12|
|  P.A               |100.5|  1.409643315E12|
|  P.A               |100.5|  1.409644709E12|
|P.B                 |  0.0|   1.40964471E12|
```

Output :

```
    +--------------------+-----+----------------+
    |          tagname   |value|timestamp       |
    +--------------------+-----+----------------+
    |  P_A               |101.5|  1.409643313E12|
    |  P_A               |100.5|  1.409643315E12|
    |  P_A               |100.5|  1.409644709E12|
    |P_B                 |  0.0|   1.40964471E12|
```

Comment: It works for me, so could you prepare some fake/test data, execute `rfm.show()` and paste here the output you're getting?

Comment: there might be some special characters which maynot not actually be simple whitespace characters. To be sure just use `rfm.select('tagname').collect()` to see what is there in those whitespaces. And then replace those characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a pattern not just the space. Provide it as below.

```
regexp_replace(col("tagname"),"\\s+"," ")
```

`\s+` is for more than one space and one more extra `\` is to escape the \ in `\s` inside method.